# Nodemon don't reload when using docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, nodemon

I am trying to setup an API and using docker/docker-compose at the same time but I am having a problem with nodemon(https://nodemon.io/).

At the moment, I can run the command: **docker-compose build && docker-compose up** and access API, but the problem is when I go to the code and change something and save, my nodemon don't reload/restart.
I was looking into the stackoverflow about this problem and some topics recommend to add "--legacy-watch" on the command to run, for me this isn't working properly.

Any idea how to fix this? 
I can provide a github access with the simple API.

Some setting:

**Folder structure:**

docker-compose.yml -> file

weather-api  -> nodeJS application

- Dockerfile
- src
- ...

**Docker compose configuration:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  weather:
    build:
      context: ./weather-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes: ['./weather-api/', '/usr/src/app/']
```

**Docker file configuration:**

```
FROM node:10.13-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "tsconfig.json", "./"]
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run dev
```

**Package json config**

```
...
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json --fix",
    "dev": "nodemon --legacy-watch src/server.ts",
    "build": "tsc -b"
  }
...
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do live development inside Docker?  I've found these tools work just fine in a plain non-Docker host development environment, and then are unnecessary once you go to deploy.  Nothing you've shown suggests any dependencies beyond Node itself and things you can easily `npm install`, so you probably have all the tools you need already.

Comment: There is a reason for using docker and docker compose, later I will put everything into AWS and I will have microservices running too. 

The reason to use nodemon is because this tool provides you the reload like JRebel for example, otherwise is just a waste of time using nodemon .

Comment: Are you using windows? Because on windows `volume` doesn't work very well